# Need to cross Compile JNI libraries in windows to run in linux using cygwin

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, cygwin

I am currently developing JNI libraries under windows environment using cygwin and deploy to linux now
my question is ..
where to download cygwin-gcc-linux.tar.bz2 please help
I am very keen on any response 
ive read this page 
http://metamod-p.sourceforge.net/cross-compiling.on.windows.for.linux.html
but seems to be that provided link for downloads do not contain the file
cygwin-gcc-linux.tar.bz2.. please help
or if there is any very simple ways to cross compile JNI for linux developed in windows help.. please.

and also if ever how can i install in on cygwin properly. please help...

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried installing Cygwin from a tar file before, but if you go to the install page on the official website, it's all pretty straightforward - just download the installer and follow the directions.

Link here: https://cygwin.com/install.html

Comment: i have already installed cygwin with other utils and gcc compiler, now what i mean is i need to build libraries using cygwin that will run in linux. please help me. any i dea? ive beed googling about cross compiler and try to follow instruction in this page http://metamod-p.sourceforge.net/cross-compiling.on.windows.for.linux.html but the libraries provided are not found cant download like cygwin-gcc-linux.tar.bz2

Comment: Just to double check, are you sure that there isn't a gcc-linux package that you can install when you install cygwin itself?  When you select which packages to install, there are quite a few that begin with gcc-.  Have you checked to see if gcc-linux is there?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Find this on following link. Select The Version and click on that and then download from the very first screen.

http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/

Comment: @Neveen thanks but what I mean and i need is not the c compiler but the cross compiler. I am developing JNI in windows , build jni will be run in Linux so i need cross compiler please help